# How to use a Go callback for a DLL with minimal Cgo?

Tags: go, dll, shared-libraries, cgo

One way to setup a callback function to be passed in to a parameter to a DLL function is to use CGO...

```
package main

/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR} -lsomelib

#include "somelib.h"

extern void CallbackString(char* s);
*/
import "C"

import (
    "unsafe"
    "fmt"
)

//export CallbackString
func CallbackString(s *C.char) {
    gostr := C.GoString(s)  // convert to golang string
    fmt.Println("Got string from dll (or dso): ", gostr)
}

func Example() {
    // setup a callback by calling a function in
    // the DLL requiring callback param
    C.SomeDLLFunc(x,y,
        (C.TCallbackString)(unsafe.Pointer(C.CallbackString)),
        other,
        params)
}


func main() {
    Example()
}
```

where the callback is defined as

```
typedef void (*TCallbackString)(char*);
```

But I am wondering if there is a way to avoid using CGO and just pass the go function in as a parameter without requiring needless C code bindings.. i.e.

```
C.SomeDLLFunc(x,y,
    CallbackString, // how to send the go function in as a callback?
    other,
    params)
```

Does it always require writing C bindings or whatever you call them, C links to the go code, C exports/externs, in order to send a callback as a param?

There is no way to just make a go function a callback without making it C-ish first?

```
C.SomeDLLFunc(x,y,
    WhatCastIsNeeded(CallbackString), // regular go function as a callback?
    other,
    params)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is some way to avoid the cast and simplify callback code.

```
// cgo.h in dll  
typedef void (*Callback)(int kind,void* arg);
void SetCallback(Callback func);

// cgo.c in dll
Callback Gfunc;
void SetCallback(Callback func){
    Gfunc=func;
}

// cgocb.h in go project
void InitCallback();
extern void goCallbackFunction(int kind,void* arg);

// cgocb.c in go project
void InitCallback(){
    SetCallback(goCallbackFunction);
}

// cgocb.go in go project
// export goCallbackFunction
func goCallbackFunction(kind C.int,arg unsafe.Pointer){
    switch kind{
    case C.AKind:
        arg:=(*C.AKind)(arg)
        AkindCallback(arg)
    }
}
```

1. The `C.InitCallback` function is similar to `C.SomeDLLFunc`.But it references `goCallbackFunction` directly without cast,since I move the code from .go to .c.
2. This is a solution about callback to go from c dll. We need to register only one go function to the dll. We write one `C.InitCallback`. Note that if we use the `C.SomeDLLFunc` solution, we must write (gocallback,dllfunc) pairs.
3. Keeping an export go function pointer in c dll is ok.